# What is the optimal way to upgrade production RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have MySQL  small RDS instance as part of my production system and I want to upgrade it to medium instance with provided IOPS.

As old-school  DBA I'm aware about "add slave; promote to master; switch clients" method, but AWS promises to provide magic one-click upgrade path, i.e. "upgrade instance", "add  provided IOPS".

Tried this on test RDS instance, downtime is too long, IMHO: about 5 min for small->medium upgrade, and 30 min (!!!) for switching to provided IOPS.

- Is this normal behavior?
- Is there any way to run upgrade on production RDS w/o downtime?
- Do you recommend "stop; create a snapshot;  restore from snapshot to bigger instance" way?

Answer (score 41):

Upgrading an instance in RDS means RDS will be physically migrating the database to a new instance, likely on a different physical host, so downtime would not be avoidable.  Migrating to provisioned IOPS would likely mean your data would be migrated to a new EBS volume (and the server might be migrated to a new instance as well with this change, depending on whether, internally, machines capable of accessing EBS volumes with provisioned IOPS are physically segregated from machines that aren't, so that they can be on a different class of network hardware) so downtime would again be inevitable.

There appears to be a way to avoid this disruption: a Multi-AZ deployment, which creates an invisible and inaccessible (to you) replica in another availability zone within the region.

> In the case of system upgrades like OS patching or DB Instance scaling, these operations are applied first on the standby, prior to the automatic failover. As a result, your availability impact is limited only to the time required for automatic failover to complete.
>
> <sup>— http://aws.amazon.com/rds/multi-az/</sup>

That *should* provide a quick and seamless migration path, though I have not had occasion to test this capability.  "Modify" in the console appears to allow you to convert an instance to Multi-AZ.  Presumably, this would result in brief I/O freeze as the instance is cloned, so I of course would recommend testing all of this functionality before trying it.

Alternately, RDS supports an internal mechanism that should allow you to emulate the "add slave; promote to master; switch clients" operation, and this also should allow you to achieve a near-zero-downtime conversion:

- Create an actual RDS read replica of your database with the desired instance class
- Wait for the replica to come online and be synched with the master
- Modify the replica's configuration to add Provisioned IOPS
- Wait for the replica to come online and be synched with the master
- Verify that both systems have identical data using 3rd party tools
- Disconnect your application from the old master
- Verify matching binlog coordinates on master and replica to assure that all application writes have replicated
- Split the systems with "Promote Read Replica" on the new replica in RDS
- Connect your application to the new master

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/11/amazon-rds-mysql-rr-promotion/

Comment: Michael, many thanks for detailed answer! Vitaly

Comment: promoting a read replica to master will cause downtime (as the instance will need to report) WATCH OUT!

Comment: @MahmoudKhateeb thank you. That is correct.  Even though there is no technical reason why this is necessary, RDS does reboot an instance when you promote it to master.   Indeed, I have learned a lot more about how RDS works in the almost 4 years (!?) since I originally wrote it.  I will make edits.

Comment: I am doing this on Production on Monday, so I might have some stuff to add. I will basically change the replica to become read/write then I am gonna point all of my services to it, then I will upgrade the master.

Comment: @MahmoudKhateeb with RDS, when you promote a replica, the connection to the master is permanently severed.  You can't go back to using the old master as master again.  The old replica is 
now a master and must remain that way.  Create a replica of the existing replica, now (RDS does support cascades)... then upgrade the new replica and the old replica as needed...  then start using the new replica as the production replica... then promote your original replica and start using it as the new master. Throw the old master away.

Comment: It seems that upgrading is now cluster-specific, not replica-specific.

Answer (score 6):

Even with a multi-AZ environment, you will have a [60-120s outage.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html#Concepts.MultiAZ.Failover)
This was the case when I repeatedly hit our RDS instances while performing an upgrade from a PostgreSQL db.m3.medium to an db.m3.large.

Answer (score 6):

**It is also POSSIBLE to avoid any downtime during the upgrade.** 
The way to do it is by briefly launching a new RDS from a read replica snapshot and configure it as active/active Master to Master replication. Once it's configured, you can switch application traffic one APP server at the time without any downtime.
We use the approach every time AWS announces RDS maintenances to avoid downtime as well as during our scheduled maintenances.

https://workmarket.tech/zero-downtime-maintenances-on-mysql-rds-ba13b51103c2

## Here are the details:

**M1** - Orignal Master

**R1** - Read Replica of the M1

**SNAP1** - Snapshot of the R1

**M2** - New Master

M2 creation sequence:
`M1 → R1 → SNAP1 → M2`

- Since we can’t use SUPER privilege on RDS, we don’t use mysqldump with `— master_data2` option on the M1. Instead, we launch R1 to obtain the **binlog position of the M1** from it. Then create a snapshot (SNAP1) from the R1 and then launch M2 from the SNAP1.
- Create two separate RDS parameters groups with the followingt offsets to avoid PK conflcts:

  `M1: auto_increment_ increment = 4 and auto_increment_offset = 1`

  `M2: auto_increment_ increment = 4 and auto_increment_offset = 2`
- Create replication user on M1

  `GRANT EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO
  ‘repl’@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>;`

**1. Create R1 from M1**

```
-- Connect to the R1 and stop replication
   CALL mysql.rds_stop_replication;
-- Obtain M1’s (!!) current binlog file and position 
        `mysql> show slave status\G
             Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000622
             Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 9135555
```

**2. Create SNAP1 from R1**

- Create M2 from the SNAP1 with the attributes obtained from M1
- Assign a parameter group to M2 with a different auto_increment_ offset from M1 to avoid M/M replication key conflicts

**4. Setup M/M replication**

```
-- Configure M2 as a slave of M1
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('m1.xyxy24.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306, 'repl', 'mypassword', 'mysql-bin.000622', 9135555, 0);
CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
-- Connect to M2 and obtain its current binlog file and position
         mysql> show master status\G
            File: mysql-bin.004444
            Position: 6666622
-- Connect to M1 and configure it to be a slave of the M2
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('m2.xyxy24.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306 , 'repl', 'mypassword', 'mysql-bin.004444', 6666622, 0);
CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
```

**5. Delete R1 and SNAP1 as they’re no longer needed**

**6. Upgrade M2 via AWS Console**

Use the standard procedure to Modify the Instance as per your needs.

**7. Perform Graceful Switchover to M2**

As M/M replication is set up successfully, we are ready to proceed with DB maintenance without downtime by gracefully switching App servers one at the time.

Here are more details on how it works.

https://workmarket.tech/zero-downtime-maintenances-on-mysql-rds-ba13b51103c2

Comment: The `show master status\G` command on my M2 returns `Empty set`. Is it `show slave status\G` or `show master status\G`?

Comment: This [post](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/) says that we can run `mysqldump` without SUPER privilege by setting `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to `true`.

Comment: M2's automated backup needs to be enabled so that running `SHOW MASTER STATUS\G;` on M2 can return `File`, and `Position`.

Comment: this is correct, make sure binary logging is enabled on both Masters

Answer (score 1):

This would work, however you must make sure that the endpoints of the RDS instance is not configured in you application as a static entry. Swapping RDS will change the endpoints.

Comment: Please give more substance to your answer such as some references to support your answer and/or extended reasoning.